# Sending value to salesforce through CURL i got following error.Please guide

Tags: validation, error, web2lead

Reason: Contract_Number__c duplicates value on record with id: 00QF000000ZgKKC     Lead Capture Page: Not available.

I received this in an email:

> Salesforce could not create this lead because of the reason listed
>   below. For more information about this error or help with
>   Web-to-Case-Lead, please contact Customer Support. Reason:
>   Contract_Number__c duplicates value on record with id: 00QF000000ZgKKC
>
> Lead Capture Page: Not available. Record Information: 00NF000000B0aOW
>   = 290 00NF000000B0aOb = 2014-05-23 17:12:43 [00NF000000BwlyI = 231456985124235] this column email = admin@admin.com encoding = UTF-8
>   encoding = UTF-8 first_name = anjum 1 last_name = khalid 1 lead_source
>   = Web oid = xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Anjum. Please understand that giving more details in your question will help us answer you better. Sharing with us what you've already tried and what part of this you don't understand enables us to answer to your needs more appropriatly.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate value error messages are typically related to unique fields or custom errors by apex or app exchange de-duplication packages.

Based on your errormessage **it is likely that the Contract_Number__c field is unique, and no 2 lead records can have the same value for that field.**  In testing with CURL, you may have tried to insert the same lead twice.

To debug this:

1. check if the field is set as a unique field
2. check if there are validation rules who could trigger that message
3. check if there are triggers that may contain that message
4. chek if there are packages installed that may be interfering with this

Comment: i m putting different values still error came.thanks for reply

Comment: your questions doesn't really provide much details based on which any correct answer can be given. I've updated my answer with a general approach on how to tackle this.

Comment: Salesforce could not create this lead because of the reason listed below. For more information about this error or help with Web-to-Case-Lead, please contact Customer Support.

Reason: Contract_Number__c duplicates value on record with id: 00QF000000ZgKKC
    Lead Capture Page: Not available.

Record Information:
    00NF000000B0aOW = 290
    00NF000000B0aOb = 2014-05-23 17:12:43
    [00NF000000BwlyI = 231456985124235] this column
    email = admin@admin.com
    encoding = UTF-8
    encoding = UTF-8
    first_name = anjum 1
    last_name = khalid 1
    lead_source = Web
    oid = xxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Do feel free to always update your question with more details, I've done so for you this time. You'll still have to look into your org where that error message could be coming from .. we can't do that for you.

Comment: Sorry for disturbance.

Comment: That's fine, but maybe you can verify in your org, if you come across any error message configured like that, and if you do not find that, edit your question with an update on what you've tried.